# How can I populate a dropdown via table field type using the default values?

Tags: table-field, drop-down, default

In the CP I have a table field called `colors`. I have two columns, "Label" and "Value".

I have populated the table with two default values "Red" and "Blue" (attached).
[image]

This table will ultimately populate a dropdown on the front end. Label being the label, and value being the value.

When I edit the entry that I have assigned the `colors` field to, the default values do not show. I can only choose "Add a row". I *do* want to be able to add/remove rows like this, but I'd like to have "Red" and "Blue" be there by default.

[image]

On the template level I create the dropdown like this:

```
{% if entry.colors|length %}
<select id="colors" name="colors">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    {% for color in entry.colors %}
        <option value="{{ color.value }}">{{ color.label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
{% endif %}
```

The drop down does not show until I enter a value in the entry. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so that the drop down will pull in the default values by...default.

Comment: You will only get the defaults for new entries! Do they show up with new entries?

Comment: What the....
I SWEAR I I TRIED THAT. 

...and yet another silly question by yours truly. Post your comment as the answer and I'll check it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only get the defaults for new entries.